# I can't activate my code in certain discord channels

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot which deletes excessive Capital letters automatically. There are some channels where I don't want to use that feature. There is some error in my code. I can't activate commands in those safe channels. But I can activate commands in rest of the channels.

This is my code. The rest of my code(commands) doesn't activate in all channels where Anti-capitalization is allowed.

Is there a way by which I can activate rest of my code in those channels where Anti-capitalization is allowed.

```py
#on_message event
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  
  #Removes Excessive Capitalization
  if Anticapitalize is True:
     
  
    if message.channel.id in allowAnticaptalize :
      return 
  
    if len(message.content) > 10:
      
      find_upper = re.findall('[A-Z]', message.content)
      x = len(message.content)
      y = len(find_upper)
      z = (y/x)*100
      if z > 80:
        
        embed = discord.Embed(title = f"**__AUTO MODERATION__**", description="Please don't write in excessive capital letters!", color = 0xff0000)
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(message.author.mention,embed=embed, delete_after=15)
      
  
  await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Your `await bot.process_commands(message)` is not run if `if message.channel.id in allowAnticaptalize:` returns `True`. You need to add `await bot.process_commands(message)` to that `if` statement, or rewrite your code so that it is always executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose `if message.channel.id in allowAnticaptalize: return` blocks your commands. You should consider putting `await bot.process_commands(message)` before that.